# What does “it” refer to in this song by Kengiston?

Tags: pronouns

To what does ‘it’ refer in [Part of Me](https://genius.com/Kensington-part-of-me-lyrics) by Kensington? What is "a part of me"?

> It is a part of me
> And it breaks my heart to see
> I was a part of you
> When no one else could be

Comment: Why not provide the full song? Is there no more than  four lines to these lyrics?

Comment: @LPH One reason is copyright. Reproducing the relevant part is fair use; reproducing the whole song when only one part is needed for the question is not fair use.

Comment: Why preserve the spelling "Kengiston" when "Kensington" is the name of the band?

Comment: Questions about interpreting lyrics probably belong on Literature SE.

Comment: Yes, please consider re-asking this on [literature.se] SE. The answer below says "there's generally no point in attempting to guess what [song lyrics] mean", but over at Literature we have a [`song-lyrics` tag](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/song-lyrics) and a bunch of people expert in interpreting obscure lyrics.

Comment: Posting the full song with attribution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

[I've no idea who Kensington is, and Google doesn't help. I'm going to use the pronoun *he.*]

Poetry and song lyrics are so intensely personal to the writer that there's generally no point in attempting to guess what they mean. Word choice could be really esoteric; or it could simply be a matter of scansion.

Here, the second *it* is the "dummy *it*" saying what breaks the singer's heart.

The first *it* can also be a dummy *it,* saying that what is a part of him is that he was a part of his lover.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Kengiston" is four guys.

Comment: @Laurel That's OK then :-) Since the song uses a singular pronoun, *he* would appear to be acceptable. Odd that I couldn't find the group though.

Comment: The second one is clearly a dummy it. But the first one is clearly not. If it was ‘it is part of me to …’ then it would be a dummy it.